# Find standard matrix A for T

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some problems while solving this problem:

[image]

I think that $A = [T(v_1) \ \ T(v_2) \ \ T(v_3) \ \ T(v_4)]$. So, $Av=T(v)$. Then I find $A = inv(v)*T$.
I don't know why my thinking is wrong? Could you please show me a fastest way to solve problems similar to this? Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean by $inv(v)$?

Answer (score 0):

Why would $A$ be equal to $\begin{bmatrix}T(v_1)&T(v_2)&T(v_3)&T(v_4)\end{bmatrix}$? This has nothing to do with the standard basis.

Note that $(1,0,0,0)=3v_1+v_2$ and that therefore$$T(1,0,0,0)=3T(v_1)+T(v_2)=(3,1,-8).$$Therefore, the entries of the first column of $A$ are $3$, $1$, and $-8$. Can you take it from here?